# Custom UITableViewCells in Child TableViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I'm setting up a view with tabs/swipes between three different UITableViewControllers

```
AllUsersTableViewController * child_1 = [[AllUsersTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
NearMeTableViewController * child_2 = [[NearMeTableViewController alloc] init];
ByInterestTableViewController * child_3 = [[ByInterestTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

However, when I try to hook each of these Controllers to prototype cells in the storyboard, I believe the prototypes aren't registered:

```
unable to dequeue a cell with identifier AllUserCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
```

Even though I did assign the identifiers properly in the storyboard. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You might have forgot to set a class for that cell.

Answer (score 0):

just call

```
[self.tableView registerClass:class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"identefier"]
```

in viewDidLoad of your controllers